# Unexpected behavior for Facebook Sharing

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-s3, facebook-javascript-sdk

First of all hi and thanks in advance to anyone who can help with this because I've been going crazy over this for weeks now.

So I've got a website which lists gif taken from my mobile application (which are then stored on AWS and my visitors ( I haven't found a use for me to have users) can share these gifs on facebook using the facebook sdk.

The problem appears when I try sharing an image for the first time

This is what the share dialog shows the first time I click on my sharing button:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNVNF.png

and then I close and reclick the same button and now it works:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsDUm.png

Now I've been trying to find a way to make this work on the first sharing attempt but to no avail.

I am using meteor in combination with biasport:facebook-sdk and Amazon S3 for the hosting of my files.

Edit here is the code used:

FRONT SIDE

HTML

```
<div class="facebook share">
    <img src="/gallery/fb.png">
</div>
```

Javascript

```
Template.*templateName*.events({
    'click .facebook': function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         e.stopPropagation();
         // this is in a modal so I store the data I need 
         // (events have photos which in turn contain a url to the gif
         var url = Session.get('event').photos[Session.get("id")].url;
         FB.ui({
             method: 'share',
             href: url
         });
}
```

SERVER SIDE

JAVASCRIPT

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {
     window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
         FB.init({
             appId      : 'APP_ID',
             status     : true,
             xfbml      : true,
             version    : 'v2.5'
         });
     };
}
```

Edit: I found a manual solution using exec future and curl

so first I added a call to a meteor method on the share that updates the facebook crawler

JAVASCRIPT

```
Template.*templateName*.events({
    'click .facebook': function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         e.stopPropagation();
         // this is in a modal so I store the data I need 
         // (events have photos which in turn contain a url to the gif
         var url = Session.get('event').photos[Session.get("id")].url;
         Meteor.call('updateCrawler', url, function(){
             FB.ui({
                 method: 'share',
                 href: url
             });
         });
}
```

Then I defined my meteor method as such

JAVASCRIPT

```
Meteor.methods({
    updateCrawler: function(url){
        var future = new Future();
        cmd = 'curl -X POST -F "id=' + url + '" -F "scrape=true" -F "access_token={my_access_token}"  "https://graph.facebook.com"';
        exec(cmd, function(error){
            if (error){
                console.log(error);
            }
            future.return();
        });
        future.wait();
    }
});
```

it's ugly but since I'd have to wait for the crawler to update and it works I'll leave this here for future use for someone maybe

Edit2:

I did not use og tags at all since I was simply sharing a url to aws directly and not a url to my website

Comment: @Kyll I've added the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this problem by calling the Facebook API direct from the server to make it scrape the og data by requesting info on the page. First time round it doesn't have the image cached but second time it does so this workaround does the initial call before sharing.

Use an access token for your facebook app and call the below in an ajax call and await the response before opening share dialog. Replace Google address with your own uri encoded address `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/?id=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk&access_token=xxxxx`

**EDIT:**

As per comments, here is my server side method for calling this which I use when posts etc are inserted to make the initial call and prompt a scrape from fb:

```
var getTheOGInfo = function (link)
{
  if (!link || link.slice(0, 4).toLowerCase() != "http"){
    throw new Meteor.Error("og-info-bad-url", "Function requires an unencoded fully qualified url");
    return false;
  }
  var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{{{{id}}}}?access_token={{{{token}}}}&fields=og_object{id,description,title,type,updated_time,url,image},id,share";
  var token = Meteor.settings.private.fb.token;
  if (!token){
    throw new Meteor.Error("og-info-no-token", "Function requires a facebook token in Meteor.settings.private.fb.token");
    return false;
  }
  var link_id = encodeURIComponent(link);
  url = url.replace('{{{{token}}}}', token).replace('{{{{id}}}}', link_id);
  var result = HTTP.get(url, {timeout:1000});
  return result;
}
```

Or for your purposes you may not want anything that might be blocking so you could change the last two lines to be aynchronous:

```
var result = HTTP.get(url, {timeout:1000});
return result;

//Replace with non blocking
HTTP.get(url, {timeout:1000}, function(err, result){console.log('something asynchronous', err, result);});
return true;
```

Comment: Thanks ! Going to try it out give you an update ASAP

Comment: I tried this using a post request but it seems to fail (server side) with Error: failed [500] {"error":{"message":"An unknown error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException","code":1,"fbtrace_id":"BT9l3M8VSA0"}}] could you maybe post your ajax request ?

Comment: Can do but not till later when I'm at the laptop, did you replace xxxxx with a valid token for the call? Possubly try it direct in browser till you have it working then out it in ajax... Also I wrote this late last night so just realised you don't need to call this every time someone shares it is sufficient to call this once on the server when the url/post is created initially

Comment: I tried it out in the browser and it worked but I used the access token I get from the graph api explorer, is there another way I can get a token (because I had to regenerate one since it first told me this token was valid for one day only) ?

Comment: Well, I say it worked, I mean by that it didn't return an error this time but the og_object type returned was "website" and not image or anything of the sort, is that relevant ?

Comment: On the image side of things I don't think you need to worry the 2.5 api doesn't return an image url but whatever is in there shouldn't be of concern, you just want to kick off an initial scrape from fb. If you change 2.5 to 2.3 I think you get the image url though. On the persistent token - https://smashballoon.com/custom-facebook-feed/access-token/

Comment: But with app token above you are probably better calling this when the gif is uploaded rather than on client side you don't want to pass you app token to the client. You only need to do it once in this case and it will speed things up for the client

Comment: I've tried several things, but by navigator it gives me the good result but using ajax it returns an error

Comment: Probably cross domain issue try adding that to your request. use `dataType: 'jsonp'`, `jsonpCallback: 'yourcallback'` and `crossDomain: true`. If that doesn't work I can send over my exact code tomorrow once I can get to my laptop and I'll pop it in the answer

Comment: Added my example for server side so you can avoid having to use curl and can use Meteor functionality instead @JamesWoodrow